# My Java Server/Client program will only work every third time I run it

Tags: java, networking, server, client

I am new to Java Programming, and even newer to Java Networking Programming, so I am sure the problem will be a simple one. My program is based around a submit button which submits the student ID to the server.

The first two times I run the program it will establish a connection with the server and then everything will crash and it will never exchange strings.

However, every third time I run it, it will work perfectly and exchange the strings as designed.

**Client:**

```
String currentButton = e.getActionCommand();
    if(currentButton == "submit"){
        try{
            Socket server = new Socket("Localhost",1234);
            InetAddress address=InetAddress.getLocalHost();

            System.out.println("Connected to "+server.getInetAddress());
            System.out.println("Connected to "+address);

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));

            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(server.getOutputStream(), true);

            pw.println(student);

            while ((student = br.readLine()) != null) {
              System.out.println(student);
              pw.println("bye");

              if (student.equals("bye"))
                break;
            }
            br.close();
            pw.close();
            server.close();
        } catch (IOException ex){
            //ignore exception
        }
    }
```

**Server**

```
class NETCW1S {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String student;
    ServerSocket serverSock = null;
    InetAddress address=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    try{
        serverSock = new ServerSocket(1234);
        System.out.println("Waiting for client connection");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 1234");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    Socket clientSock = null;
    try{
        clientSock = serverSock.accept();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Accept Failed");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Connected to "+address);
        System.out.println("Waiting for client...");
        Socket client = serverSock.accept();

        System.out.println("Client from "+client.getInetAddress()+" connected.");

        Socket fromClientSocket = serverSock.accept();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fromClientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fromClientSocket.getInputStream()));

        while ((student = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("The message: " + student);

            if (student.equals("bye")) {
                pw.println("bye");
                break;
            } else {
                student = "Server returns " + student;
                pw.println(student);
            }
        }
        pw.close();
        br.close();

        fromClientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Performing close in your try clause is a bad idea!  If an exception is thrown prior, you will not close your streams/connections, which may explain your problem as well.  Also equally bad if not worse is *hiding exceptions*!  Don't do it, not even when you're not expecting them!

Comment: What exactly does "everything will crash" mean?

Comment: Hi Neil, if I move the close's outside of the try, the program wont compile and generates the error 'NETCW1.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
  br.close();'

Comment: Jiri, the small GUI that I have will freeze up so I cannot press the submit button anymore!

Comment: @GeorgeMahon Read about "try-with-resources", if you use Java7 or newer. For the freezing: I guess you're running all this stuff on the GUI Thread. Never do that.

Answer (score 0):

The server should only have one accept() call, inside the loop. The client needs to make a connect() call at some point - right now it doesn't appear to be talking to the client at all.